# How to change settings of an index after creation in elastic4s?

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I'd need to disable index refreshing for the course of a batch indexing (of gigabytes)  and set it back again after it's done. But from the source code of elastic4s I can't find a way to do it other than at index creation time... Is it possible? Or is there a workaround for this?

In java client :

```
client
  .admin
  .indices()
  .prepareUpdateSettings()
  .setSettings(settings)
  .setIndices(indexName)
  .execute()
  .actionGet()
```

Natively :

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my_index/_settings' -d '
{
    "index" : {
        "refresh_interval" : -1
    }
}
'
```

Comment: You can't. I'll add it to the API and do an answer once ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you do it in elastic4s (for example setting the refresh interval property).

```
client.execute {
  update settings "myindex" set Map("index.refresh_interval" -> "10s")
}
```

**Note:** Not all settings can be changed at runtime or after the index is created.

**Note 2:** I have added this API in response to your question, and is only available in version 1.5.1 onwards.

**Note 3:** I could back port it to 1.4.x or 1.3.x if required by anyone.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot, no need for back porting afaic

Comment: is there a way to update higher level (node,cluster) settings? Those that don't relate to an index but to a node like `indices.store.throttle.type: none`

Comment: You can change some, using the put settings api. But some are set on the node themselves and can't be changed by the client.